# How to fix SyntaxError in conda

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm testing new software, everything is ok with setup. while running this command on terminal:

```
python data-processing/run_pipeline.py default.yaml test.fasta ./tmp_feature
```

I'm getting this error:

```
File "data-processing/run_pipeline.py", line 29
    print "=" * 60
            ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("=" * 60)?
```

Please, can you help me to fix this error?

I tried to change the command by adding a parentheses:

```
 python (data-processing/run_pipeline.py) default.yaml test.fasta ./tmp_feature
```

since run_pipeline.py is file included in data-processing but it didn't work and I got this error

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `data-processing/run_pipeline.py'
```

Comment: Looks like the problem in line 29 in run_pipeline.py. Show it please. Are you sure you use python 2.7 in conda?

Comment: this is the line 29 in run_pipeline.py "  print "=" * 60
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error suggests that the code was meant to be run with Python2 as Python3 requires parentheses with `print` but Python2 does not. Therefore, you are probably just using the wrong Python version. Check your python version with `python -V` on the command line. If you are on Windows, you should be able to run:

```
py -2 data-processing/run_pipeline.py default.yaml test.fasta ./tmp_feature
```

Basically, you want to make sure you have Python2 installed and that you are using that version.

Comment: I'm working on linux system, and I'm using the latest version of python 3.7.
How can I change to python 2.7? what if I add the missing parentheses in the code?

Comment: For the same command with python 2.7, I had this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data-processing/run_pipeline.py", line 8, in <module>
    import yaml
ImportError: No module named yaml

Comment: Glad it worked out. I imagine you just had to reinstall the proper modules for the new python.

Comment: The yaml module is installed but I'm getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'

Comment: Are you sure its installed for python2?

Comment: no, I'm using python 3.7
Python 2.7 will reach its end on next jan 1st, before switching to python 3.7, I had the same error with python 2.7

Comment: I tried "pip install yaml" and I got this error: " ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement yaml (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for yaml"

Comment: @islemhabibi You should try `pip install pyyaml` then. See [link](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/1320)

Comment: @islemhabibi no problem!